Объясните мне динамическое программирование
Я перечитал много ресурсов, но так до конца и не понял. Как можно в рекурсии идти снизу верх? Как решается задача о рюказаке при помощи него?

А что именно вы читали и не поняли? А то вдруг мы то же самое повторим... И "снизу-вверх" - это не рекурсия.

Динамическое программирование - не про рекурсию, а про специальный метод решения задачи. Когда решение задачи может быть составлено из решений задач меньшего размера. Если к ним добавить решение всех задач малого размера, то можно решить исходную (большую задачу). Аналог динамического программирования в математике - метод математической индукции.

Использование рекурсии в динамическом программирование называется "ленивой динамикой", когда переход в динамике легко виден, то можно написать рекурсию и с помощью мемоизации запоминать посчитанные ответы.
Это может быть полезным https://wiki.algocode.ru/index.php?title=%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0.
